# I keep getting an error about the wrong number of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, class, arguments, parameter-passing, superclass

I'm a student, and I'm trying to figure out what I have done wrong. Could anyone spot what I might have done?

```
super(Fighter, self).__init__(modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, 0, 0, 0, 3.0, )

TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)**
```

Code:

```
 class Fighter(ShowBase, object):
    fighterCount = 0
    def __init__(self, modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, posVec, traverser, scaleVec = 1.0):
        super(Fighter, self).__init__(modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, 0, 0, 0, 3.0, )

        self.modelNode.setScale(scaleVec)
        self.modelNode.setPos(posVec)

        self.trav = traverser

        self.origin = render.attachNewNode("origin")
        self.origin.setPos(0, 0, 0)
        self.origin.hide()

        self.setKeyBindings()

        self.hud = Hud("./Tools/Hud.x", self.modelNode, "Hud", (0, 10, 0))
```

Comment: There should be 6 arguments (if you want to change `scaleVec`), you provided 7. (You also put a comma after 3.0 in the super statement.

Comment: Please see [mcve], particularly the *complete* part. You need to include the code for `ShowBase`.

Comment: @Rohen, but the error says `__init__() takes at most 3 arguments`, so I suspect Amy has some vital missing code that's not being shown.

Comment: Could you share the code for `ShowBase`?